# PHP mkdir get dynamic path

Tags: php

I am using mkdir like so

```
mkdir('somePath\\' . $this->name. '-' . $this->generateRandomString(), 0777, true);
```

The output can be something like

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\someFolder\templates\generated\Nick-ycolYWzdin
```

So, I append a name and random string as the folder name. Problem is, I now need to use PHP to put a file in this folder.

Is there any way to get the path of the folder I just created, including the folder name (with the name and generated string)?

Thanks

Comment: Seriously? Just save it in a variable...

Comment: ^ and store it in $_SESSION if you need to use it in another place/time.

Comment: Just because it's an easy question doesn't make it a bad question.  Don't discourage, please.

Comment: In all fairness, it was slightly silly now I look at it - been doing too much coding today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

store the mkdir parameter in a variable prior to calling the mkdir function.

```
$path = 'somePath\\' . $this->name. '-' . $this->generateRandomString();
mkdir($path, 0777, true);
/*
Other stuff happens
*/
move_uploaded_file($file, $path);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should store the path in a variableand pass it to mkdir function

```
$new_path = ''somePath\\' . $this->name. '-' . $this->generateRandomString()';
if (mkdir($new_path)) {
     copy($file, $new_path."/".$file);

}
```